# Hyperlink not functional/appearing on CSS hover

Tags: html, css

I have a hyperlink in my test script.

When I hover over the div, a magnifying glass appears. I should also be able to click and visit Google, but this fails.

Why isn't the link working?

Thanks for any help.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vhcfha6s/

```css
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(23, 165, 195, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
ul li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
.imgCont {
  display: table-cell;/*set display to table cell*/
  vertical-align: middle;/*add vertical align middle*/
  text-align: center;/*add text align to center for horizontal align too*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/500x500');background-position: 0 0;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;height:300px;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>
      <span class="text-content"><span class="imgCont"><img src="http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-image-rollover/images/mag.png" style="min-width:121px" /></span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your anchor is blank, if you wright something inside anchor you can track where is anchor displaying and where is your mouse cursor.

Comment: Wrap your <a> tag to your target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `span`s inside the `a` tag. Currently, your `a` doesn't have any content and hence is 0px x 0px small.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/500x500');background-position: 0 0;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;height:300px;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
            <span class="text-content"><span class="imgCont"><img src="http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-image-rollover/images/mag.png" style="min-width:121px" /></span></span>
        </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've edited your post:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhcfha6s/2/

You just have to wrap the link around your two "span" elements. Like this:

```
    <ul>
  <li>
    <div style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/500x500');background-position: 0 0;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;height:300px;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
      <span class="text-content"><span class="imgCont"><img src="http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-image-rollover/images/mag.png" style="min-width:121px" /></span></span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

its closed the anger tag before the hover area. you need to close the anchor tag ofter the viable hover area like

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/vhcfha6s/3/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
<span class="text-content"><span class="imgCont"><img src="http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-image-rollover/images/mag.png" style="min-width:121px" /></span></span>
</a>
```